# What Does Compile`SetIterate Do?

Tags: functions, compile, undocumented, contexts, sets

The list of compilable functions (given by `` Compile`CompilerFunctions[] // Sort ``) shows one of the more interesting- and core-sounding functions: `` Compile`SetIterate ``. It does not appear in the Mathematica Documentation Center. Moreover,  except for references to merely the list of compilable functions, a search for `` Compile`SetIterate `` on the Mathematica Stack Exchange comes up with nothing and a Google search for `` Compile`SetIterate `` reveals nothing I can see relating to Mathematica.

What does `` Compile`SetIterate `` do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sets an iterator:

```
cfun = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  Table[If[x == 2, Compile`SetIterate[x, 4]]; x, {x, n}]
  ]
```

Note that `2`  and `3` are skipped and the entries beyond the `x = n` one are junk:

```
cfun[5]
(*  {1, 4, 5, -5, 0}  *)

cfun[8]
(*  {1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5244412656, 5244438248}  *)
```

You need to truncate the table to avoid the uninitialized entries.
[A table of size `n` is preallocated, and essentially a for-loop intializes the table entries.  Here `` Compile`SetIterate `` short-circuits the for-loop and the initialization.]

Comment: I would think that decreasing the iterate would cause the loop to overrun the end of the table, but no error is given and you get a table of size `n`. E.g. ``Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Block[{go = True},  Table[If[go && x == 4, go = False; Compile`SetIterate[x, 2]]; x, {x, n}] ] ][8]``