# Changing iterator inside a Table?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Consider

```
Table[
 If[i == 3, i = i + 2;];
 i
 , {i, 1, 10}]
```

> {1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

The above output is not what I would expect (namely `{1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`).

> Is there a way to dynamically change an iterator variable inside `Table` while it executes? If so, what is the appropriate syntax?

Comment: Why not use a `Do` loop instead?

Comment: @Syed I imagine to generate a table using `Do` one would have to first define `output={};` and then do `AppendTo[output,i]` on every iteration. But that would create a whole new table on every iteration, which is very inefficient. Besides, doing `Do` instead of `Table` and using `Print[i]` suffers from the same issue.

Comment: You can do it in `Compile`, sort of: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255724/what-does-compilesetiterate-do

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's interesting! Keeping track of the total number of loops then would give a way to get the desired table.

Comment: What you syntactically desire and your expected output are two different things...can you, please, clarify if you are trying to “skip” over the iterators you define, or are you trying to redefine the value of the iterators? Put another way, will you have a list of length 10 or length 8, in this example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There aren't many functions that create indeterminate-length lists. `NestWhileList` comes to mind.  `Sow`/`Reap`, `Append`, `Join` etc. can be used with other iterators to create a list of an arbitrary length. `FoldWhileList[f, givenlist,...]` does not create a list longer than `givenlist`.

Here's a way to rewrite `Table` in terms of `NestWhileList` that allows the iterator to have its value changed.  (You can create an infinite loop this way, as the usual risk with while loops.)

```
withDynamicIterator // ClearAll;
withDynamicIterator // Attributes = {HoldAll};
withDynamicIterator[
  Table[expr_, {x_, a_ : 1, b_, c_ : 1}]
  ] :=
 Block[{x},
  x = a;
  NestWhileList[# &[expr, x += c] &, Nothing, x <= b &]
  ]
```

OP's example:

```
withDynamicIterator@Table[
  If[i == 3, i = i + 2;];
  i, {i, 1, 10}]

(*  {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}  *)
```

An example in which the iterator is set back:

```
SeedRandom[2];
primedQ[pressure_] := pressure >= 1;
p = 0;
withDynamicIterator@Table[
  If[i == 3 && ! primedQ[p], i = i - 3];
  p += RandomReal[{0.01, 0.3}];
  i, {i, 1, 10}]

(*  {1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}  *)
```

Comment: (+1)!!! The example with pressure is mind-numbingly awesome! I am excited to share this with some of my local mathematica friends who are still learning. It’s easy (for me) to forget that you can use `+=` & the-like within things like `Table`. Absolutely great example & answer.

Answer (score 9):

Use the correct iterator for the job, in this case use `While` instead of `Table`:

```
In[19]:= Module[{i = 0, list = {}},
    While[++i <= 10,
        If[i == 3, i += 2];
        AppendTo[list, i]
    ];
    list
 ]

Out[19]= {1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

If you don't like the performance penalty associated with `AppendTo` there are [plenty of alternatives](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=alternative+to+appendto).

Comment: The only answer that actually gives the desired output and a downvote?  :-P

Comment: Don't worry, I already gave you a vote. It's fair.

Comment: Thanks!  The downvote could be because I don't actually use `Table` and modify the iterator's value (because that isn't possible).

Comment: "...because I don't actually use `Table`..."  — people are always posting workarounds without directly answering the OP's question. You'd think for an impossible request it would be the preferred sort of answer, or at least that such helpfulness wouldn't be discouraged.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: I misunderstood the question, but the technique remains. Don't try to redefine the iterator symbol, just use it as is.

```
Table[If[3 < i < 5, Nothing, i], {i, 1, 10}]    
(* {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

In general, you should not think of symbols as being equivalent to the "variables" of other programming languages. If you really want a symbol with a mutable definition, you should probably localize it with `Module`.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Table[If[i == 3, j := i + 2, j := i];
 j, {i, 1, 10}]


(*  {1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Condition`:

```
Table[
i /.a_:>Nothing/;2<a<5
, {i, 1, 10}]
```

> {1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10}

If somehow you need to define the iterators to skip prior to evaluation, or want to control this without rewriting the `Table`:

```
ClearAll[n];
n=3;
Table[
i /.a_:>Nothing/;n<=a<n+2
, {i, 1, 10}]
```

> {1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10}